# Issue with User Assigned Identity with Azure Application Gateway while using with Terraform

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to assign a "User Assigned Identity" to my Azure Application Gateway so that the App Gateway can read SSL certs from a particular Azure Key Vault.
I am following the link --> https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/application_gateway

In the Identity section it says the block needs to be like this :

```
 identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [User Assigned Identities that need to be assigned to the App Gw ]
  }
```

My code blocks are given below for Terraform :

## User Assigned Identity for App GW

```
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "app-gw-identity" {
  location            = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.location
  name                = format("app-gw-id-%s", var.project.environment.name)
  resource_group_name = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.name
}
```

## Adding User Assigned Identity to My Designated AAD Group , this group already has Certificate Officer Role Assigned in the Azure KV where the SSL Certs are Stored

```
resource "azuread_group_member" "mygrpmember" {
  group_object_id  = data.azuread_group.cloud_developer_group.id
  member_object_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.app-gw-identity.principal_id
}
```

## Azure Application Gateway

```
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "application_gateway" {
  name                = module.names-default.location.application_gateway.name_unique
  resource_group_name = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.name
  location            = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.location
  enable_http2        = true

  sku {
    name = "WAF_v2"
    tier = "WAF_v2"
  }

  waf_configuration {
    enabled          = true
    firewall_mode    = "Prevention"
    rule_set_type    = "OWASP"
    rule_set_version = "3.2"
  }


  autoscale_configuration {
    min_capacity = 1
    max_capacity = 5
  }


  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "waf-ipconfig"
    subnet_id = module.virtualnetwork["centralus"].virtual_network.subnets["waf"].id
  }

  # HTTP port used for customer traffic

  frontend_port {
    name = "front-http"
    port = 443
  }

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "feip-config"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.waf-pub-ip.id
  }

  dynamic "ssl_certificate" {
    for_each = local.app_gateway.ssl_certificate
    content {
      name = ssl_certificate.value.name
      data = ssl_certificate.value.data
    }
  }

  dynamic "backend_address_pool" {
    for_each = local.app_gateway.backend_address_pools
    content {
      name = backend_address_pool.value.name
      fqdns = [format("%s.azurewebsites.net", backend_address_pool.value.app_service_name)
      ]
    }
  }

  dynamic "backend_http_settings" {
    for_each = local.app_gateway.backend_http_settings
    content {
      name                                = backend_http_settings.value.name
      path                                = backend_http_settings.value.path
      protocol                            = backend_http_settings.value.protocol
      port                                = backend_http_settings.value.port
      cookie_based_affinity               = backend_http_settings.value.cookie_based_affinity
      request_timeout                     = backend_http_settings.value.request_timeout
      probe_name                          = backend_http_settings.value.probe_name
      host_name                           = backend_http_settings.value.host_name
      pick_host_name_from_backend_address = false
    }
  }

  dynamic "http_listener" {
    for_each = local.app_gateway.http_listener
    content {
      name                           = http_listener.value.name
      frontend_ip_configuration_name = http_listener.value.frontend_ip_configuration_name
      frontend_port_name             = http_listener.value.frontend_port_name
      protocol                       = http_listener.value.protocol
      host_name                      = http_listener.value.host_name
      ssl_certificate_name           = http_listener.value.ssl_certificate_name
    }
  }

  # Routing rule used to redirect customer traffic to the backend  

  dynamic "request_routing_rule" {
    for_each = local.app_gateway.request_routing_rule
    content {
      name                        = request_routing_rule.value.name
      rule_type                   = request_routing_rule.value.rule_type
      http_listener_name          = request_routing_rule.value.listener_name
      url_path_map_name           = lookup(request_routing_rule.value, "url_path_map_name", null)
      redirect_configuration_name = lookup(request_routing_rule.value, "redirect_configuration_name", null)
    }
  }

  dynamic "redirect_configuration" {
    for_each = local.app_gateway.redirect_configuration
    content {
      name                 = redirect_configuration.value.name
      redirect_type        = redirect_configuration.value.redirect_type
      target_listener_name = redirect_configuration.value.target_listener_name
      include_path         = redirect_configuration.value.include_path
      include_query_string = redirect_configuration.value.include_query_string
    }
  }

  dynamic "url_path_map" {
    for_each = local.app_gateway.url_path_map
    content {
      name                               = url_path_map.value.name
      default_backend_address_pool_name  = url_path_map.value.default_backend_address_pool_name
      default_backend_http_settings_name = url_path_map.value.default_backend_http_settings_name

      dynamic "path_rule" {
        for_each = url_path_map.value.path_rules
        content {
          name                       = path_rule.value.name
          paths                      = path_rule.value.paths
          backend_address_pool_name  = path_rule.value.backend_address_pool_name
          backend_http_settings_name = path_rule.value.backend_http_settings_name
          firewall_policy_id         = path_rule.value.firewall_policy_id
        }
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "probe" {
    for_each = local.app_gateway.probes
    content {
      name                = probe.value.name
      host                = probe.value.host
      path                = probe.value.path
      protocol            = probe.value.protocol
      interval            = probe.value.interval
      timeout             = probe.value.timeout
      unhealthy_threshold = probe.value.unhealthy_threshold
      match {
        status_code = probe.value.status_code
      }
    }
  }

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = ["azurerm_user_assigned_identity.app-gw-identity.principal_id"]
  }

  tags = local.tags
}
```

But when i do Terraform Plan it throws me the below error :

```
│ Error: parsing "azurerm_user_assigned_identity.app-gw-identity.principal_id": expected 8 segments within the Resource ID but got 1 for "azurerm_user_assigned_identity.app-gw-identity.principal_id"
│ 
│   with azurerm_application_gateway.application_gateway,
│   on resources.appgw.tf line 577, in resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "application_gateway":
│  577:     identity_ids = ["azurerm_user_assigned_identity.app-gw-identity.principal_id"]
│
```

I am not sure what is the issue here as the output of the "user_assigned_identity" that i am creating can be either --  id, client_id, principal_id or tenant_id.

So initially i tried just "id" and it failed. When i tried "principal_id" in the identity block, it is still throwing this error

Answer (score 0):

I have checked with following code where I used   identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.app-gw-identity.**principal_id** ] .

Which gave the below error.

```
│ Error: parsing "82xxxa4ad": expected 8 segments within the Resource ID but got 1 for "82cxxxa4ad"
│
│   with azurerm_application_gateway.network,
│   on main.tf line 276, in resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "network":
│  276:     identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.app-gw-identity.principal_id ]
```

***Code:***

```
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "network" {
  name                = "example-appgateway"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  sku {
    name     = "Standard_v2"
    tier     = "Standard_v2"
    capacity = 2
  }

  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "my-gateway-ip-configuration"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.frontend.id
  }

  frontend_port {
    name = local.frontend_port_name
    port = 80
  }

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }

  backend_address_pool {
    name = local.backend_address_pool_name
  }

  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = local.http_setting_name
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    path                  = "/path1/"
    port                  = 80
    protocol              = "Http"
    request_timeout       = 60
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = local.listener_name
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    frontend_port_name             = local.frontend_port_name
    protocol                       = "Http"
  }

  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = local.request_routing_rule_name
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = local.listener_name
    backend_address_pool_name  = local.backend_address_pool_name
    backend_http_settings_name = local.http_setting_name
    priority = 10
  }

  identity {
    type = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.app-gw-identity.principal_id ]
  }
}
```

[image]

***It needs to be the object id of the user assigned identity.***

- So, identity must be changed to identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.app-gw-identity.**id** ]code:

code:

```
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "network" {
  name                = "example-appgateway"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  sku {
    name     = "Standard_v2"
    tier     = "Standard_v2"
    capacity = 2
  }

  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "my-gateway-ip-configuration"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.frontend.id
  }

  frontend_port {
    name = local.frontend_port_name
    port = 80
  }

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }

  backend_address_pool {
    name = local.backend_address_pool_name
  }

  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = local.http_setting_name
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    path                  = "/path1/"
    port                  = 80
    protocol              = "Http"
    request_timeout       = 60
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = local.listener_name
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    frontend_port_name             = local.frontend_port_name
    protocol                       = "Http"
  }

  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = local.request_routing_rule_name
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = local.listener_name
    backend_address_pool_name  = local.backend_address_pool_name
    backend_http_settings_name = local.http_setting_name
    priority = 10
  }

  identity {
    type = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.app-gw-identity.id ]
  }
}
```

This got executed successfully

[image]

[image]

[image]